# How can I make my 2 bot player Tic Tac Toe program determine whether it is a draw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, bots, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe that is played by two bots, the tic tac toe works perfectly and shows me who wins but it breaks when they draw, I have tried different solutions as to trying to fix it but I have no clue how it's done. Basically the bots choose a random number from a list of 1-9 and that number corresponds to a place on the board which then turns into an "O" or an "X". If they get three in a row they win. For every move, the number generated randomly will be deducted from the list and that would make the other bot choose a number that hasn't been used yet and vice versa. The issue here is when the game draws(list becomes empty) I have no idea how to stop it and prompt the user with a message that says draw or X/O won.

This is the program:

```
import random,time
xoro = ["X","O"]
line1 = [1,2,3]
line2 = [4,5,6]
line3 = [7,8,9]
pause = False
starter = ""
botlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def displayboard():
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print(line1)
    print(line2)
    print(line3)


def xbot():
    botnumber = random.choice(botlist)
    if botnumber in line1:
        for n,i in enumerate(line1):
            if botnumber == i:
                line1[n] = 'X'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return("X")
    elif botnumber in line2:            
        for n,i in enumerate(line2):
            if botnumber == i:
                line2[n] = 'X'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return "X"
    elif botnumber in line3:     
        for n,i in enumerate(line3):
            if botnumber == i:
                line3[n] = 'X'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return "X"

def obot():
    botnumber = random.choice(botlist)

    if botnumber in line1:
        for n,i in enumerate(line1):
            if botnumber == i:
                line1[n] = 'O'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return("O")
    elif botnumber in line2:            
        for n,i in enumerate(line2):
            if botnumber == i:
                line2[n] = 'O'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return "O"
    elif botnumber in line3:     
        for n,i in enumerate(line3):
            if botnumber == i:
                line3[n] = 'O'
                botlist.remove(i)
        return "O"

def checkwin():
    if line1[0] == "X" and line1[1] == "X" and line1[2] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line2[0] == "X" and line2[1] == "X" and line2[2] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line3[0] == "X" and line3[1] == "X" and line3[2] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[0] == "X" and line2[0] == "X" and line3[0] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[1] == "X" and line2[1] == "X" and line3[1] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[2] == "X" and line2[2] == "X" and line3[2] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[0] == "X" and line2[1] == "X" and line3[2] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[2] == "X" and line2[1] == "X" and line3[0] == "X":
        return "X"
        pause = True
    elif line1[0] == "O" and line1[1] == "O" and line1[2] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line2[0] == "O" and line2[1] == "O" and line2[2] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line3[0] == "O" and line3[1] == "O" and line3[2] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line1[0] == "O" and line2[0] == "O" and line3[0] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line1[1] == "O" and line2[1] == "O" and line3[1] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line1[2] == "O" and line2[2] == "O" and line3[2] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line1[0] == "O" and line2[1] == "O" and line3[2] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True
    elif line1[2] == "O" and line2[1] == "O" and line3[0] == "O":
        return "O"
        pause = True

def checkdraw():
    if not botlist:
        return True
    else:
        return False
returned = ""
def start():
    return(random.choice(xoro))


winner = checkwin()
draw = checkdraw()
while (winner == None) or (draw == False):
    displayboard()
    if returned == "X":
        returned = obot() 
    else:
        returned = xbot()
    winner = checkwin()
    draw = checkdraw()
displayboard()
if winner == "X":
    print(f"Winner is {winner}")
elif winner == "O":
    print(f"Winner is {winner}")
else:
    print(f"Game draw? {draw}")
```

The main issue is right here at the end.

**Thank you very much for reading.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `while` loop condition.

It should not be an `or` but an `and`. You want to continue the loop when both those conditions hold (i.e. there is no winner, **and** it is not a draw), and exit when *either* one does not hold (i.e. there is a winner **or** it is a draw):

```
 while winner is None and not draw:
```